# Máscara e Validação de Campo para Celular

Tags: javascript

Poderiam me ajudar com essa validação? O campo "txtTelCel" deverá ter o formato ####-####, onde # é um dígito numérico e, caso não esteja nesse formato, deverá aparecer um aviso informando o usuário.

Obs.: sem usar jQuery.

```html
<label for="txtTelCel">Telefone Celular:</label></div>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="txtTelCel" name="txtTelCel" size="50" maxlength="8">
</div>
```

Comment: Já tentou usar o https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ ?

Comment: preciso que seja em JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Mude o atributo `maxlenght` para 9 e use está função no `onblur`.

```
 function validarTel() {
    var tel = document.getElementById('txtTelCel').value;
    var pattern = /^\d{4}-\d{4}$/;

    if(!pattern.test(tel))
        alert('Número de telefone inválido!');
 }
```